# How to free a linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, valgrind, free, doubly-linked-list

I am making a linked list in C and need some help freeing it. The structures for the elements and the whole list look like this:

```c
typedef struct node_ {
    int num;
    struct node_ *next;
    struct node_ *prev;
} element;


typedef struct list_ {
    element **first;
    element **last;
    int *e_count;
} list;
```

Here is my problem with freeing the list. This code works fine:

```c
void wipe(list l) {
    element *p = *l.first;
    element *t;

    while (p) {
        t = p;
        p = p->next;
        free(t);
    }

    *l.first = NULL;
    *l.last = NULL;
    *l.e_count = 0;
}
```

But when I try to use double pointers, I start getting an **InvalidRead** error from valgrind:

```c
void wipe(list l) {
    element **p = l.first;
    element **t = l.first;

    while (*p) { // InvalidRead here after "free(*t);"
        *t = *p;
        p = &(*p)->next;
        free(*t);
    }

    *l.first = NULL;
    *l.last = NULL;
    *l.e_count = 0;
}
```

This is expected because in this case `t` and `p` are essentially pointing to the same address which is then being used by `free()`. I am wondering how is it possible to fix this and whether it would be better than the first case with the single pointers.

*Thank you for your help!*

Code example:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct node_ {
    int num;
    struct node_ *next;
    struct node_ *prev;
} element;


typedef struct list_ {
    element **first;
    element **last;
    int *e_count;
} list;


list new_list();
void delete_list(list l);

element *alloc_element(int n);

int append(list l, int n);
void wipe(list l);


int main() {
    list l = new_list();
    append(l, 5);
    append(l, 7);
    delete_list(l);
}


list new_list() {
    element **first = malloc(sizeof(element*));
    element **last = malloc(sizeof(element*));
    int *n = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *first = NULL;
    *last = NULL;

    list list = {first, last, n};
    return list;
}


void delete_list(list l) {
    wipe(l);
    free(l.first);
    free(l.last);
    free(l.e_count);
}


element *alloc_element(int n) {
    element *e = malloc(sizeof(element));
    if (!e) {
        return NULL;
    }
    e->next = NULL;
    e->prev = NULL;
    e->num = n;
    return e;
}


int append(list l, int n) {
    element **p = l.first;
    element *e = alloc_element(n);
    if (!e) {
        return 1;
    }

    while (*p) {
        if (!(*p)->next) {
            e->prev = *p;
        }
        p = &(*p)->next;
    }

    *p = e;
    *l.last = e;
    ++*l.e_count;
    return 0;
}


void wipe(list l) {
    element *p = *l.first;
    element *t;

    while (p) {
        t = p;
        p = p->next;
        free(t);
    }

    *l.first = NULL;
    *l.last = NULL;
    *l.e_count = 0;
}
```

Comment: For what reason are you using **, this isn't required for a link list, and ** is a pointer to the address of a pointer.

Comment: @Mikhail Stefantsev For starters this data member declaration int *e_count; does not make sense. At least you need also to free the memory pointed to by the pointer. Also using a double pointer in the function does not make sense. And these declarations     element **p = l.first;
    element **t = l.first; are invalid.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Also compile your code with all warnings enabled and consider warnings as errors. Also don't hide pointers behind `typedef`s, it only adds confusion.

Comment: @Jabberwocky
[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cMRyjs7nBIoqZaMrsxaQxKH_wFvVWABV) is the example.

Comment: Please [edit] you question instead linking to other place somewhere in the net. Some people refuse to follow links (for good reasons) or can't do this.

Comment: C function calls pass parameters by value. Your `append(l, 5);` call will pass a _copy_ of `l` (a `struct list_`) to the `append` function. `append` modifies its copy of the `struct list_` but this does not change the caller's `l` variable. I suggest modifying the code to use `list *` instead of `list`.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thank you, I will rewrite the code to use `list *`.

Comment: Looks like your code may be trying to dereference null.  Just change your loop to `while(p)`.

Comment: @JimFell I very much doubt that it can dereference `NULL`, but it does in fact try to dereference a _freed chunk_ of memory, which will result in an undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need the functions to modify the `list` you need to pass pointers to `list` to the functions. Also, there seems to be a lot of confusion in your code about the use of double pointers which can be avoided.  Here is a tidied up version of the code which fixes all the mess:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct node_ {
    int num;
    struct node_ *next;
    struct node_ *prev;
} element;


typedef struct list_ {
    element *first;
    element *last;
    int e_count;
} list;


list *new_list(void);
void delete_list(list *l);

element *alloc_element(int n);

int append(list *l, int n);
void wipe(list *l);


int main(void) {
    list *l = new_list();
    append(l, 5);
    append(l, 7);
    delete_list(l);
}


list *new_list(void) {
    list *l = malloc(sizeof(list));
    if (!l) {
        return NULL;
    }
    l->first = NULL;
    l->last = NULL;
    l->e_count = 0;
    return l;
}


void delete_list(list *l) {
    if (l != NULL) {
        wipe(l);
        free(l);
    }
}


element *alloc_element(int n) {
    element *e = malloc(sizeof(element));
    if (!e) {
        return NULL;
    }
    e->next = NULL;
    e->prev = NULL;
    e->num = n;
    return e;
}


int append(list *l, int n) {
    element *e = alloc_element(n);
    if (!e) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (l->last) {
        l->last->next = e;
    } else {
        l->first = e;
    }
    e->prev = l->last;
    l->last = e;
    ++l->e_count;
    return 0;
}


void wipe(list *l) {
    element *p = l->first;
    element *t;

    while (p) {
        t = p;
        p = p->next;
        free(t);
    }

    l->first = NULL;
    l->last = NULL;
    l->e_count = 0;
}
```

Comment: I realized my version of the `append()` function wasn't setting the `next` pointers, but I've fixed it now.